# Cannot write to efivars

Tags: command-line, kernel, permissions, uefi

I have booted from an Ubuntu 17.10.1 live DVD on a 2011 MacBook Pro (in EFI mode) and I'm trying to issue the following command to disable the discrete GPU:

`printf "\x01\x00\x00\x00" > /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/gpu-power-prefs-fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9`

And I am getting this error no matter what I do:

`bash: printf: write error: Invalid argument`

I know this question has been asked and answered before, but I have already verified that the `efivars` filesystem is mounted `rw` and I have removed the immutability flag with `chattr -i`.

I can `touch` the file to create it, and I can delete it with `rm`, but any attempt to actually write data to the file at all results in a write error, whether I use `echo`, `printf`, or try to `cp` or `mv` the file from another writeable directory.  Nothing seems to work.

I have also tried this in Debian and that didn't work either.

Those that are familiar with the MacBook Pro GPU bug might suggest that I boot into single user mode and issue an `nvram` command from there, but the laptop does not have an operating system installed to boot into (and I can't install macOS because of the GPU).

Is there no way to write to `efivars` anymore?

Comment: Did you try booting using cmd-option-r and booting to the MacOS / internet recovery option? From there, open a terminal (it's in one of the pull downs on the first page) and you can use Apple's "nvram" command to write to the NVRAM? I haven't used this for GPU issues but did while trying to disabled the Apple "bong" on bootup after a bare metal Ubuntu install to a macbook pro7,1.

Answer (score 1):

I think the command is wrong. I successfully used:

```
printf "\x07\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00" > /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/gpu-power-prefs-fa4ce28d-b62f-4c99-9cc3-6815686e30f9
```

Found [here](https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/force-2011-macbook-pro-8-2-with-failed-amd-gpu-to-always-use-intel-integrated-gpu-efi-variable-fix.2037591/).

Note that [in some resources](https://realmacmods.com/macbook-2011-radeon-gpu-disable/) the backslashes are missing (leading to the same error message).